# How can I make Software Updater stop asking me for my password?

Tags: 22.04, update-manager

I would like Software Updater to never ask me for my password. I still want to be asked for my password if I try to install new software by any other method. What are my options?

Comment: @user535733 It asks if there are kernel updates, for instance. I want it to stop asking in situations like that.